# Get path folder in java when run with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a project with 1 package and 1 folder:
1 is package. pathpackage:"project/src/java/basebusiness"
2 is folder . pathfolder:"input/run"
In folder I have a text file CNPM.file, in package 1 I have a class ReadOrWriteFile. Here is code in ReadOrWriteFile:

```
public static List<String> ReadFileTXT(String pathFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        List<String> lst_result= new ArrayList<>();
        String path= new File("input\\run").getAbsolutePath();
        path+= pathFile;
        BufferedReader bR= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line="";
        while((line= bR.readLine()) != null){
            lst_result.add(line);
        }
        bR.close();
        return lst_result;
    }
```

I want to get path of the folder in the project when i run the code in tomcat.
 I have write the code and run it in console but it's not running as web.I'm using tomcat 8.0.9 and window. Please help me.

Comment: You don't do that when you run a webapp. You use resources on a classpath. In a webapp context, unless you explicitly have a need to, you never access files directly.

Comment: you have to make another project, a web project

Answer (score 2):

You want a path of webapp such as `/tomcat/webapps/mywebapp/` folder? You need ServletContext reference to read a path at runtime. If you are at JSP page context it is an implicit application variable.

```
    // any servlet giving getServletContext() getter
    String path = ctx.getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println(path);
    - - - - 
    // in .jsp page
    String path = application.getRealPath("/");
```

Or use resourceloader interface to read from classpath as one of the comment said. Another portability hint is always use unix-like path `input/run`  delimiter even in Windows box. Java can handle it fine.

Comment: i want get path of forder in my source code  as src/java/basebusiness/folder. Please help me !!!!!