# In tomcat Server the file is "Path to file not found", while inside psvm it is found

Tags: java, tomcat, path, filenotfoundexception

In basic Java I have a very odd issue,
In the same java class I have a method and a PVSM containing the same info:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println(htmlToString("src/main/Java/archive/trawler/webservices/emailHTMLTemplates/resetMail.html"));
        System.out.println(htmlToString("src\\main\\Java\\archive\\trawler\\webservices\\emailHTMLTemplates\\resetMail.html"));
```

Above it finds it without issue, but when I try and run it within a method it reports it cannot find it. Errorcode at the bottom:

```java
    public static boolean sendMailWithToken(String sendTo, String subjectLine, String token) throws FileNotFoundException {
            String htmlMessage = htmlToString("src\\main\\Java\\archive\\trawler\\webservices\\emailHTMLTemplates\\resetMail.html");
```

```java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\Java\archive\trawler\webservices\emailHTMLTemplates\resetMail.html (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at archive.trawler.webservices.SendEmail.htmlToString(SendEmail.java:161)
    at archive.trawler.webservices.SendEmail.sendMailWithToken(SendEmail.java:121)
    at archive.trawler.webservices.accountResetResource.resetWachtWoord(accountResetResource.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
[...]
at setup.HttpsFilter.doFilter(HttpsFilter.java:28)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:57)
```

I have hardcoded the location in now for easier testing:

```java
    public static String htmlToString(String htmlFileFromRoot) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
//            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(htmlFileFromRoot));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/resetmail.html"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                contentBuilder.append(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return contentBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Litterally only using absolute path seems to work.. !
But still no luck in anything else.. here is my directory structure
[image: Directory tree]

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that src is the repository root for the project in which sendMailWithToken is called.

Comment: cheers dmena :) 
I now marked it as Sources Root, but no luck still.. mind you I am running the method in tomcat, could be ?  I have also added the files to a folder in src/main/resources marked as resources and then tried referring as "resetmail.html" and "/resetmail.html" but all to no avail im afraid

Comment: It would help if I could see the code for the htmlToString method

Comment: What did you mark as source root? I don't have much experience with tomcat. The resources folder doesn't change the path root, it should still be from the repository root

Comment: src/main/resources/resetmail.html 
this is the path from Content Root and Repository Root according to Intellij

Comment: src/main/resources/resetmail.html seems to work in the file in the psvm but just not running on the server.. which is odd because it's run backend I guess from a JAX-RS request.. so it shouldnt change much ?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you get the absolute path for resetmail.html.

Comment: If it doesn't work, It is probably something to do with tomcat(which I don't have experience in). I would start from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792340/get-path-folder-in-java-when-run-with-tomcat  Hope you find your answer

Comment: glimmer of hope ! absolute path works!

Comment: yeah thanks for your help! :) can't be far now... (famous last words)